# Error in compiling GWT code that use JBoss errai

Tags: java, gwt, errai

I'm having problem compiling my gwt application, it uses JBoss Errai, and here is the complete stack trace:

http://pastebin.com/U7X6w1gb

It seems that the error is caused by this:

> RuntimeException: error loading marshalling extension:
>   org.jboss.errai.enterprise.rebind.ObserversMarshallingExtension

Comment: Your root cause seems to be `Unable to load class "org.jboss.errai.marshalling.server.impl.ServerMarshallingFactoryImpl"`.

Comment: Does that class have a default constructor? Or does it have any class that GWT does not emulate?

Comment: Actually this class is not even there in my project

Comment: I finally fixed this error by removing "dead" codes, but was not really able to pinpoint the problem